# How to make a constant current-pulse current charger for lithium ion?

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, buck, pulse, constant-current

I've been doing some research about battery charging system with the CC-PC-CV (constant current-pulse current-constant voltage) method. However I have some questions and need some guidelines for proper implementation.

Basically I am trying to find out if:

1. Is it possible to make the charging system with DC-DC buck converter?
2. If possible how to change from CC mode with output 1C-rate to pulse current 4C-rate.

If you don't mind, can you explain with PSIM schematics?

Comment: Q1 Please provide some web references to pulse current charging. || Q2 CCCV is VERY common - what advantages are you hoping for from CCPCCV? Q3 Manufacturers may specs fro charging current are often C or C2 max. What batteries do you propose to use 4C charging with? Do the manufacturers cover this in their specifications?

Comment: A1: references https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/9/2/227/htm , https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8591173 || A2: I hope with compare CC and PC can reduce time of charging || A3: based form ieee journal "Charging Techniques in Lithium-Ion Battery Charger: Review and New Solution"

Comment: More soon maybe - but this may prove useful - [Lithium-ion battery fast charging : A review](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S2590116819300116?token=BE4F2B4D27EB88838289117FB31E4590EEF520107E666959CD2455664C6B777A19C3DB46F2785CC9056576028FD70CD8)

Answer (score 1):

To do CCCV charging with a DC2DC you need to provide it with 2 regulation loops, one for current, one for voltage. Thus when the battery is flat, it will operate in CC, when nearly full, CV - a common way of doing this is to add an op-amp or high-side current sense arrangement to sense current in the positive lead (e.g. TI's INA180) of a DC2DC (set for the correct voltage) and use the output of this op-amp to steal current (often through something like a current mirror/matched transistor pair) from the DC-DC converter's comp pin, thus robbing the output of current to prevent it exceeding a certain limit. If there isn't a COMP pin available it can sometimes be done through the FB node, but be VERY careful of stability due to the high gain here.

However, Analog devices(Linear tech) and other manufacturers offer several IC's with many of these features built in, for a price. They have entire categories of their web site on switching chargers and pulse chargers.

Unless you are very familiar with DC2DC converters and what makes them unstable, AND wish a low-cost highly customised solution, I recommend you rather use an existing part and follow an application note closely.

A lot also depends on the size of battery you are charging, and if there are more than one in series, as to which solution becomes practical, as a battery management IC will become necessary for more than 2 in series.

Another point to note is that DC-DC converters will add current limiting in the inductor current already - if you aren't averse to running your converters hot (ambient temperature is never high and charger is well ventilated), and don't care if the current limit is accurate, this can sometimes be used to limit current - however, read the datasheet with care if doing this.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. He is asking about adding pulse charging to the normal CCCV cycle to increase charging speed.